# WordPress : Genesis Framework Custom Nav CSS Class

Tags: html, css, wordpress, nav, genesis

I am using a custom child theme with Genesis Framework.

I am not trying to replace the default menu with my own, I only wish to add a custom class name to the existing  element, which currently displays **header right** (since my menus is in the the header right widget).

How can I go about achieving this? I have tried using the `nav_menu_css_class` filter in my child's `function.php` file without success.

Answer (score 0):

Each menu you create in WordPress will apply that menu name as the ID preceded by menu.  So if you have a menu named Top Menu the id of that UL would be menu-top-menu so the UL would look like this `<ul id="menu-top-menu" class="menu"`.  You could target the menu using the ID.

Alternately, if you create a menu called 'Top Menu', you could call it directly in a theme file using `wp_nav_menu`.  Using this technique will allow you to add a class.  In the example below I am adding a class called `top-menu`.

```
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Top Menu', 'menu_class' => 'top-menu' ));
```